# How to Run the TesNG xml file from Command prompt?(Please explain in detail)

Tags: java, testng, selenium-webdriver

I am working in selenium web-driver using java test-ng framework. I have created testng xml file to run the scenario combined from java class. Like below.I run this xml file from eclipse successfully.
Can anyone help me how to run it from command prompt?(please explain in detail)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <suite name="Manual Lab Suite" parallel="false">
    <test name="Manual Lab Order Test" preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
    <class name="demoappln.html" preserve-order="true">  
    <methods preserve-order="true">  
    <include name="testHt"/> 
    </methods> 
    </class> 
    </classes>
    </test>
    </suite>
```

**UPDATE**

I entered the Following line in command prompt

```
java -Dtestng.test.classpath="C:\Documents and Settings\000278\.m2\repository\org\testng\testng\6.3.1;C:\Documents and Settings\000278\ATLAS\POC_Workspace\SampleProject\src\main\java\demoappln\NewFil‌​e;"org.testng.TestNG NewFile.xml
```

But I am getting the following error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: what have you done? Show the code..

Answer (score 0):

The [TestNG documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng) explains in detail how to do this.  If you don't understand some aspect of the documentation's explanation, feel free to ask a more *specific* question.

---

> It shows "Could not find the main class:NewFile.xml"

That means that it is trying to interpret "NewFile.xml" as the name of a Java class.  The problem is that you are missing a space before `org.testng.TestNG`, so `java` thinks that `org.testng.TestNG` is part of the previous argument!  In fact, `org.testng.TestNG` is meant to be the name of the

Your command may still fail after fixing the above.  You may not have `org.testng.TestNG` on the JVM's initial classpath.  (The `-Dtestng.test.classpath=...` stuff is not setting the JVM's initial classpath.  Rather it is setting a system property the TestNG understands.)

If if now fails saying "Could not find the main class:org.testng.TestNG", you need to add the TestNG JAR file to the JVM classpath.

---

For what it is worth, your mistakes are basic java command-line syntax stuff.  I recommend that you carefully read/reread the `java` manual entry, paying close attention to the command line syntax, what `-D...` options mean, and how to set the JVM classpath.

Comment: Hi Stephen as per the doc I entered the Following line in command prompt  

java -Dtestng.test.classpath="C:\Documents and Settings\000278\.m2\repository\org\testng\testng\6.3.1;C:\Documents and Settings\000278\ATLAS\POC_Workspace\SampleProject\src\main\java\demoappln\NewFile;"org.testng.TestNG NewFile.xml  

But I am getting the following error Please help me If I am wrong

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with the classpath.  What class is it saying is not found?